# Проблемы с блоком после :hover

Tags: javascript, css

Как видно из примера что после `:hover` остаётся место от скрола, и так же после скрола в низ - само содержимое остаётся на месте - по замыслу должно вернуться в исходное состояние и без этого места от скролла , каким способом этого можно добиться ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.mw {
  width: 220px;
  height: 318px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img,
.text {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.mw:hover {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mw">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5206/natali73123.157/0_3dab0_8a253738_L.png" alt="Шуба">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">  -Что такое «пластины» и «роспуск»?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">
-Какие шкурки лучше — самца или самки?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">
-Как происходит выделка и обработка шкур?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">
-Крашение и стрижка - какая норка лучше: натуральная, крашеная, тонированная, стриженная?</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант задать ширину в пикселях для `.img, .text` и `margin: 10px auto` заменить на `margin: 10px`. А возврат прокрутки - на js, когда курсор покидает элемент - задавать `scrolltop = 0`

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.mw');
el.onmouseleave = function() {
    el.scrollTop = 0;
 }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.mw {
  width: 220px;
  height: 318px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img,
.text {
  width: 198px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}
.mw:hover {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mw">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5206/natali73123.157/0_3dab0_8a253738_L.png" alt="Шуба">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">  -Что такое «пластины» и «роспуск»?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">
-Какие шкурки лучше — самца или самки?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">
-Как происходит выделка и обработка шкур?</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">
-Крашение и стрижка - какая норка лучше: натуральная, крашеная, тонированная, стриженная?</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: во, отличное решение по поводу сколлбара, а по поводу вернуться в верх ?

Comment: @Geyan Изменил ответ, добавил возврат прокрутки на js

Comment: блеск , спасибо